# Apache POI problem writing multiple ppt slides with master slide

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

We are trying to write information inside a ppt with an application using Apache POI.
For this, we are using a ppt template containing two master slides.
We are only programmatically editing those two master slides (containing header and footer) and saving the edited ppt again.
We are facing just one strange issue: if the powerpoint contains more than 8 slides, apache POI somehow deletes a master slide (one out of two), and the content written in the master gets mixed up. Until 8 slides, everything is working.

Did someone face this kind of issue in the past? Couldn't find anything related

thanks for your help

Already tried to narrow down to the content, but even empty slides above 8 are corrupting the ppt master slide.

Comment: If you can create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which displays this problem, you should file a bug report with the Apache POI project. You could also post it here to see if anyone can find a work around.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it. Also, the system uses Apache POI 3.9. Tested with 5.2 and the problem disappeared. Unfortunately we can't switch to the new version easily for now.